# Crispy forms with Jinja2 in Django 1.8

Tags: django, jinja2, django-crispy-forms

Now that Django has built-in support for Jinja2, does any one know of a way to use crispy forms with the Jinja2 template backend?

I am really interested in using Jinja2, but would really like to use a form helper other than the built-in Django form library. Our projects have been using crispy forms exclusively for some time now.

If this is not possible yet, is there something which makes working with forms easier with Django and Jinja2?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364980/django-crispy-forms-with-jinja2) and [this](https://github.com/datouch/jinja-form-helper) is a tiny form helper for jinja2.

Comment: Thanks for the macro suggestion. I had seen the first answer before, but was wondering if anything else is available which can make use of a form helper.