# Django crispy form and jinja2 2

Tags: jinja2, django-crispy-forms

1.My project app folder is :service. Under service/templatetags.py with following code

```
from jinja2 import contextfunction
from crispy_forms.utils import render_crispy_form
from django_jinja import library

@contextfunction
@library.global_function
def crispy(context, form):
    return render_crispy_form(form, context=context)
```

2.forms.py

```
   class ServiceRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):      
      class Meta:
          model = ServiceRequest
          fields = (
                'client', 'service_type', 'request_description', 'request_date', 'expected_complete_date'
                )
```

3.Jinja2 template: My template is under template/services/servicerequest_form.html with following code

```
{% extends 'services/services_sidebarbase.html' %}
{% block sidebarcontent %}  
     {# {% load crispy_forms_tags  %} removed #}        
     <h4>Service request form</h4>      
     <form  method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
        {% autoescape true %}            
           {{ crispy(form)}}            
        {% endautoescape %}  
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>             
     </form> 
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to follow the instruction given to question related to jinja2 and crispy form But it did not work for me. I am getting an error like crispy undefined when I called crispy(form) in jinja2 template.
[django crispy forms with jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364980/django-crispy-forms-with-jinja2)

To me, it's sound like the above solution has dependency with package `django-jinja` which I installed. 
I have installed crispy form as per instruction is given below.
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-django-crispy-forms

I am a bit new to django. I am using jinja2 2.10 with django 2.0 and `django-crispy-form 1.7.2`
I would really appreciate if someone guides me to sort this issue out.

Thanks 
Rajesh

Comment: Can you provide your code where you get your error? Just telling "I followed the instructions, still get error" unfortunately doesn't give much room for something to review upon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this tag to TEMPLATES in settings.py ?
Like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "match_extension": ".jinja",
            "filters": {
                "crispy": "service.templatetags.crispy",
            },
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: My template setting 
TEMPLATES = [    
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'mates.jinja2.environment',            
            },
    }
]
If I change template setting as given by you, my pages failing to render.I understood django-jinja completely different template engine than jinja2. I need to find a way to used crispy form with jinja2 template engine not django-jinja.

Comment: I set TEMPLATES as given by you for  django-jinja settings.I had to change few syntax in template to compatible with django-jinja but now i get new error ->Could not parse the remainder: '(form)' from 'crispy(form)'

Comment: Perhaps django doen't use jinja2 for rendering templates. 
Check template extension. It has to be ".jinja"  if you use my config. Depends on "match_extension" in TEMPLATES.

Comment: Django-jinja is just extension, it has build-in templatetags, filters.It uses jinja2 for rendering. But you have to register new templatetag for crispyform in jinja enviroment.